# Listing inside Jframe, Which will take you to its detail view

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am a PHP Developer in Profession and also a student. So i Have A Question To ask For My Ongoing College Project in Java.

First let me explain the situation I am in, I am creating a Stand Alone App in Java Swing with JDBC. The project is similar to a website. The project will have four modules (SuperUser, Company, Employee, & Project).

When the app will start user will see login page.

[image: Login Page]

If user is not registered he/she can register by clicking on sign up button.

There are two type of user "1" admin and "2" employee.

Admin will have option to go to admin in home page after a successful Login.

But employee will only have access to front end.

[image: Front End Page]

So I will need a listing of all the projects. I can also do that

But my problem is when user will click on the button inside the project listing

Which of course will be dynamically generated from Database !!

With Their Different id's

?? Is it possible to see the detail of a project. Just like in websites ??

Thank you so much for giving your precious moment for my question !!
I will really appreciate any help, I am stuck in this problem for more than 
6 days. I've tried searching every where on the internet,I Could not find
any answer.

Hope you guys will help

Comment: *"So i Have A Question To ask For My Ongoing College Project in Java."*  Words that are randomly capitalised are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling one moment, and SHOUTING the next.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle, but not otherwise.

Comment: I will keep that in mind when i will ask another question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to see the detail of a project. Just like in websites

Yes. Basically, if you use something like a `BorderLayout`, you can place a `JList` to the `WEST` position, and the detail panel to the `CENTER` position.

When an item is selected, you can populate the details view with the data you want to display

Start by having a look at [How to use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to use BorderLayouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) as starting point

Answer (score 0):

> No one answered what i was looking for !!
>   I've completed the project and here is the answer

```
DbConnect con = null; 
        try { con = new DbConnect(); } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        // Retreiving Results 
        try {
            ResultSet res = null;
            res = con.selectQueryBig("select * from tbl_company where owner_id='"+User_Session.getSessionId()+"' ORDER BY id Desc");

            int i=1; 
            if (res!= null){
            while(res.next()){
                //Titles
                PanelDynamic[i] = new JPanel(new WrapLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,0));
                PanelDynamic[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,40));
                if (i%2 == 0) {
                    PanelDynamic[i].setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,255));
                } else {
                    PanelDynamic[i].setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,200));
                }

                // Name Of Company
                LabelDynamic[i] = new JLabel(res.getString("name"));
                LabelDynamic[i].setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.LEFT );
                LabelDynamic[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240,40));
                LabelDynamic[i].setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));

                // Created date
                LabelDynamicB[i] = new JLabel(res.getString("created"));
                LabelDynamicB[i].setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.LEFT );
                LabelDynamicB[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170,40));
                LabelDynamicB[i].setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));

                // Created date
                LabelDynamicC[i] = new JLabel(res.getString("updated"));
                LabelDynamicC[i].setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.LEFT );
                LabelDynamicC[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170,40));
                LabelDynamicC[i].setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));

                // Button For Read More
                ButtonDynamic[i] = new JButton("Edit");
                ButtonDynamic[i].setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.LEFT );
                ButtonDynamic[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
                ButtonDynamic[i].setBorderPainted(false);
                ButtonDynamic[i].setFocusPainted(false);
                ButtonDynamic[i].setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,0));
                ButtonDynamic[i].setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));
                ButtonDynamic[i].setIcon(EIco);
                ButtonDynamic[i].setActionCommand( Integer.toString(res.getInt("id")) );

                PanelDynamic[i].add(LabelDynamic[i]);// title
                PanelDynamic[i].add(LabelDynamicB[i]);// Created
                PanelDynamic[i].add(LabelDynamicC[i]);// Created
                PanelDynamic[i].add(ButtonDynamic[i]);// Edit

                panelBoxin.add(PanelDynamic[i]);
                panelBoxin.revalidate();

                i+=1;
            }}
            res.close();
            ResLength = i;
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        // Closing Connection
        try { con.release(); con.disconnect(); } 
        catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
```

what we really need to do is, we have to generate buttons dynamically with action commands = primary key id.

and we have to write button action in a loop

```
// Dashboard Button Actions
public class ListenerForCompany implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
// Edit Button Array
        for (int i=0; i< AdminViewObj.ResLength(); i++){
            if(e.getSource()==AdminViewObj.ButtonDynamic[i]){

                // Parsing id
                Integer id =Integer.parseInt(AdminViewObj.ButtonDynamic[i].getActionCommand());

                // loading screen and thread
                AdminViewObj.loadingView.setVisible(true);
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        try {

                            ProjectManagement.CompanyAddEditView(id);
                            AdminViewObj.dispose();

                            }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            AdminViewObj.loadingView.setVisible(false);
                            AdminViewObj.ErrorMessage("Could not connect to server");
                        }
                    }

                }).start();

            }// end of for
        }
```

Comment: A JList with a custom renderer to display a POJO would have been simpler